# Android Studio "not assignable to android.app.activity" and "no default constructor" errors

Tags: java, android, constructor, default

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saf1T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZUBs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T3HB.png)

Am a complete beginner to Java and AS. 
Trying to make a revision app in the form of quizzes. Please let me know what advice you d give for these errors.

tried to add a public default constructor though I guess incorrectly.

I expect to be able to call this class from another one to calculate score and progress for questions

Comment: Please post your actual code rather than a screenshot.

Comment: you're not extending anything in your `QuestionModel`. Also please paste your code instead of screenshots

Comment: ah okay sorry am new on here

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Angela

Activity is one of main component of Android and Android OS is responsible for instantiation of this components.

But in Action for defining an activity we should extending `AppCompatActivity` like this :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);

    }
```

And DO NOT create a constructor for activities.